# django-file-picker setup.py broken?

Tags: installation, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to install django file picker, but for whatever reason, it appears that there is a problem with the setup.py. I'm not familiar with how setup works, so it might be something easy to fix, but I can't tell. Stack traces follow.

I'm doing this on windows, in a virtualenv with python 2.7.2.

From inside the unpacked package:

```
>python ./setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating django_file_picker.egg-info
writing requirements to django_file_picker.egg-info\requires.txt
writing django_file_picker.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to django_file_picker.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to django_file_picker.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'django_file_picker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'django_file_picker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    zip_safe=False, # because we're including media that Django needs
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 76, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 96, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 167, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 177, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run
    self.read_template()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 162, in read_template
    sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['template'].close()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\text_file.py", line 128, in close
    self.file.close ()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

From outside the downloaded package:

```
>pip install ./caktus-django-file-picker-c1d628d
    Unpacking c:\users\marcin\documents\oneclickcos\caktus-django-file-picker-c1d628d
      Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///c%7C%5Cusers%5Cmarcin%5Cdocuments%5Coneclickcos%5Ccaktus-django-file-picker-c1d

        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
          File "c:\users\marcin\appdata\local\temp\pip-2kgmcr-build\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
            zip_safe=False, # because we're including media that Django needs
          File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "<string>", line 12, in replacement_run
          File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources
            mm.run()
          File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run
            self.read_template()
          File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 162, in read_template
            sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['template'].close()
          File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\text_file.py", line 128, in close
            self.file.close ()
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        running egg_info

    creating pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info

    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\requires.txt

    writing pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\PKG-INFO

    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\top_level.txt

    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

      File "c:\users\marcin\appdata\local\temp\pip-2kgmcr-build\setup.py", line 25, in <module>

        zip_safe=False, # because we're including media that Django needs

      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "<string>", line 12, in replacement_run

      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources

        mm.run()

      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run

        self.read_template()

      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 162, in read_template

        sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['template'].close()

      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\text_file.py", line 128, in close

        self.file.close ()

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

    ----------------------------------------
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
    Storing complete log in C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log

    (oneclickcos) C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos>python caktus-django-file-picker-c1d628d\setup.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "caktus-django-file-picker-c1d628d\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
```

From pypi:

```
>pip install django-file-picker
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-file-picker

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\build\django-file-picker\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        zip_safe=False, # because we're including media that Django needs
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "<string>", line 12, in replacement_run
      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run
        self.read_template()
      File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 162, in read_template
        sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['template'].close()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\text_file.py", line 128, in close
        self.file.close ()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info

writing requirements to pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\requires.txt

writing pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\django_file_picker.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\build\django-file-picker\setup.py", line 25, in <module>

    zip_safe=False, # because we're including media that Django needs

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "<string>", line 12, in replacement_run

  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 252, in find_sources

    mm.run()

  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run

    self.read_template()

  File "C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 162, in read_template

    sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['template'].close()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\text_file.py", line 128, in close

    self.file.close ()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same error and in my case it was caused by a trailing slash in one of the paths in my MANIFEST.in file.

For some strange reason this crashes distutils.  So instead of

```
recursive-include foo/bar/
```

use

```
recursive-include foo/bar
```

Same for graft, prune, etc.